# Issue recognizing text in image with pytesseract python module

Tags: python, image-processing, python-tesseract

I have the attached an image with 300 DPI. I am using the code below to extract text but I am getting no text. Anyone know the issue?

`finalImg = Image.open('withdpi.jpg')`
`text = pytesseract.image_to_string(finalImg)`

[image to extract text from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP5Pt.jpg)

Comment: btw for some reason the moment I upload the image here it reduces the dpi to 96

Answer (score 1):

Lets observe what is your code doing.

---

- We need to see what part of the text is localized and detected.
- For understanding the code behavior we will use `image_to_data` function.
- `image_to_data` will show what part of the image is detected.
- ```py
  # Open the image and convert it to the gray-scale
  finalImg = Image.open('hP5Pt.jpg').convert('L')

  # Initialize ImageDraw class for displaying the detected rectangle in the image
  finalImgDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(finalImg)

  # OCR detection
  d = pytesseract.image_to_data(finalImg, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)

  # Get ROI part from the detection
  n_boxes = len(d['level'])

  # For each detected part
  for i in range(n_boxes):

      # Get the localized region
      (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])

      # Initialize shape for displaying the current localized region
      shape = [(x, y), (w, h)]

      # Draw the region
      finalImgDraw.rectangle(shape, outline="red")

      # Display
      finalImg.show()

      # OCR "psm 6: Assume a single uniform block of text."
      txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped, config="--psm 6")

      # Result
      print(txt)
  ```

Result:

- ```py
  i
  I
  ```

```

- [image]
- So the result is the image itself displays nothing is detected. The code is not-functional. The output does not display the desired result.
- There might be various reasons.
- Here are some facts of the input image:

  - Binary image.
  - Big rectangle artifact.
  - Text is a little bit dilated.

---

- We can't know whether the image requires [pre-processing](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) without testing.
- We are sure about the big-black-rectangle is an artifact. We need to remove the artifact. One solution is selecting part of the image.
- To select the part of image, we need to use [`crop`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) and some trial-and-error to find the roi.

  - If we the image as two pieces in terms of height. We don't want the other artifact containing half.
  - From the first glance, we want (`0` -> `height/2`). If you play with the values you can see that the exact text location is between (`height/6` -> `height/4`)
- Result will be:
- ```py
  $1,582
  ```
- [image]
- Code:

---

- ```py
  # Open the image and convert it to the gray-scale
  finalImg = Image.open('hP5Pt.jpg').convert('L')

  # Get height and width of the image
  w, h = finalImg.size

  # Get part of the desired text
  finalImg = finalImg.crop((0, int(h/6), w, int(h/4)))

  # Initialize ImageDraw class for displaying the detected rectangle in the image
  finalImgDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(finalImg)

  # OCR detection
  d = pytesseract.image_to_data(finalImg, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)

  # Get ROI part from the detection
  n_boxes = len(d['level'])

  # For each detected part
  for i in range(n_boxes):

      # Get the localized region
      (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])

      # Initialize shape for displaying the current localized region
      shape = [(x, y), (w, h)]

      # Draw the region
      finalImgDraw.rectangle(shape, outline="red")

      # Display
      finalImg.show()

      # OCR "psm 6: Assume a single uniform block of text."
      txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped, config="--psm 6")

      # Result
      print(txt)
  ```

If you can't get the same solution as mine, you need to check your pytesseract version, using:

```py
print(pytesseract.get_tesseract_version())
```

For me the result is `4.1.1`